# Create a new space using a keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, applications, macos, applescript, mission-control

I am aware you can do it from Mission Control by clicking and there is no shortcut available in 'Keyboard'.

**Are there any ways to do this by using a 3rd party program or Applescript?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very helpful question for my workflow. I'd also like to know about your desktop background!

Comment: Glad you liked the question :) Here is a link to the wallpaper http://www.somethingpeach.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/wallpaper_2880x1800_001.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: This method works in OS X 10.11 and earlier at least to OS X 10.8 (didn't test it on anything older then OS X 10.8) but no longer works as coded in macOS 10.12 due to significant changes to Mission Control made by Apple.

---

To programmatically add a Desktop in Mission Control the *code* below can be used as an AppleScript or a BASH Script in conjunction with an Automator Service using Run AppleScript or Run Shell Script, respectively, and a key sequence assigned to the Service in System Preferences in Keyboard Shortcuts.

---

**AppleScript Code:**

```
do shell script "open -a 'Mission Control'"
delay 0.5
tell application "System Events" to click (every button whose value of attribute "AXDescription" is "add desktop") of group 1 of process "Dock"
delay 0.5
tell application "System Events" to key code 53
```

---

**BASH Script Code:**

```
#!/bin/bash

open -a 'Mission Control'
osascript -e 'delay 0.5' \
          -e 'tell application "System Events" to click (every button whose value of attribute "AXDescription" is "add desktop") of group 1 of process "Dock"' \
          -e 'delay 0.5' \
          -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code 53'
```

---

- Open **Automator** and select **Service**.
- Set: Service receives no input in any application
- Add either a **Run AppleScript** or **Run Shell Script** *Action*.
- Add the appropriate *code* for the target *Action*.
- Save the *Service* as, e.g.: *Add New Desktop*
- Assign a keyboard shortcut for the *Service* in **System
  Preferences**.

**Note:** You'll have to assign a key sequence that is not used elsewhere on the *System* or in *Finder* if you choose is over *any application* in the *Service*.

I tested it with: ⌃⌥⌘D (Control-Option-Command-D)

Comment: Thanks this worked great. Do you think you could make a second script for deleting spaces?

Comment: @Jonathan, Adding a Desktop is sort of a kludge, programmatically, to begin with and possible because there is an AXButton with the AXDescription of "add desktop" that can be clicked however the AXButton(s) under Mission Control with AXTitle, e.g. "Desktop 2", while it has a close element (a circle with a x, in the top left corner of the button) it is not addressable in the same manner as there is no "remove desktop" button. So I really do not know of an easy way to remove one programmatically, sorry.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for taking the time to explain it to me

Comment: I've tried this in macOS (10.12.1) and haven't had any luck. It opens Mission Control for the .5 seconds but the New Desktop button isn't pressed.

Comment: @portOdin, If you look at the Tags on the OP it shows el-capitan and that is what this was tested under and it works there. Every release of the OS brings about its own issues as well as breaking _code_ that worked in previous OS versions. When I get a moment I'll try it under macOS Sierra and see if I can get it to work there.

Comment: @user3439894 Yes, I was just commenting in case someone had an answer for MacOS. I hadn't considered creating a separate question; should I? Thanks though, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

OK, using the Automator recording, I made it work with a revised version of the AppleScript in the other answer.

Replace "of group 1" with "of group 2 of group 1 of group 1 of":

```
on run {input, parameters}

    do shell script "open -a 'Mission Control'"
    delay 0.5
    tell application "System Events" to click (every button whose value of attribute "AXDescription" is "add desktop") of group 2 of group 1 of group 1 of process "Dock"
    delay 0.5
    tell application "System Events" to key code 53

    return input
end run
```

Comment: The checked answer didn't work for me, but this one did =)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, that works, sort of. Problem is that user3439894's solution ends up throwing an error if the active application (Finder, textedit, etc.) hasn't been added to the Security & Privacy Accessibility pane.

To get around this, we need two workflows, user3439894's service with the updated group list as an Automator application, and a second Automator service to launch it.

The Automator Application (Saved into /Applications as "New Desktop".)

> on run {input, parameters}
>
> do shell script "open -a 'Mission Control'"
>
> delay 0.5
>
> tell application "System Events" to click (every button whose value of attribute "AXDescription" is "add desktop") of group 2 of group 1 of group 1 of process "Dock"
>
> delay 0.5
>
> tell application "System Events" to key code 53
>
> return input
>
> end run

Then we just need to create the second workflow as a service, using the "Launch Application" action and save it as "New_Desktop"

Last steps are to add “New Desktop.App” to  System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Accessibility

Then add your keyboard shortcut in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services > General for the New_Desktop.workflow.