# Create a new space using a keyboard shortcut in macOS Big Sur

Tags: keyboard, applescript, spaces, mission-control

I am aware you can do it from Mission Control by clicking and there is no shortcut available in 'Keyboard'.

Are there any ways to do this by using a 3rd party program or Shell/ Applescript?

The solution presented [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234606/create-a-new-space-using-a-keyboard-shortcut) only doesn't work in Big Sur anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested under **macOS Big Sur** and **macOS Catalina** using **English (US)** as the language, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works to programmatically add another **Desktop**:

```applescript
do shell script "open -a 'Mission Control'"
delay 0.5
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    click (every button whose value of ¬
        attribute "AXDescription" is "add desktop") of ¬
        group 2 of group 1 of group 1 of process "Dock"
delay 0.5
tell application "System Events" to key code 53
```

Note that most likely works from **macOS Sierra** onwards. Prior to that, remove `group 2 of group 1 of`  from the *code*.

---

For other languages, including **English**, try the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
do shell script "open -b 'com.apple.exposelauncher'"
delay 0.5
tell application id "com.apple.systemevents"
    tell (every application process ¬
        whose bundle identifier = "com.apple.dock") to ¬
        click (button 1 of group 2 of group 1 of group 1)
    delay 0.5
    key code 53 -- esc key
end tell
```

Comment: This only opens and closes Mission control for me. Maybe it has something to do with my language being German? When I use this code: `tell application "System Events"
 tell application "Mission Control" to launch
 tell group 2 of group 1 of group 1 of process "Dock"
  click (every button whose value of attribute "AXDescription" is "add desktop")
 end tell
 
end tell` it returns "missing value"

Comment: My intuition was right, I switched my language to English (GB) and now it WORKED. Thanks for letting me know that this solution works at all. 
I assume I could find out the AXDescription in german using some XCode tools (Accessability inspector) is this right or is there an easier way?

Comment: @Fyn, See the updated answer, specifically the _code_ under "For other languages, including **English**, try the following example AppleScript code".  I believe it will work while using **German** as the language in **System Preferences** .

Comment: Yes works like a charm using German. I could even reduce the delay down to 0.01 but that may only work because I have already sped up animations in Terminal.