# Remove a Desktop Space using Applescript

Tags: applescript, spaces

Thanks to **@user3439894**'s response to this post: [Create a new space using a keyboard shortcut in macOS Big Sur](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/407422/create-a-new-space-using-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-macos-big-sur), and because my System language is French, I use Keyboard Maestro and the following Applescript to create 4 new Spaces when launching an app ↓

```
do shell script "open -b 'com.apple.exposelauncher'"
delay 0.5
tell application id "com.apple.systemevents"
    tell (every application process ¬
        whose bundle identifier = "com.apple.dock") to ¬
        repeat 4 times
            click (button 1 of group 2 of group 1 of group 1)
        end repeat
    delay 0.5
    key code 53 -- esc key
end tell
```

It works perfectly, and now I'd like to do the opposite: **Remove these Spaces** when I leave the app.

Unfortunately, I'm too new to this universe to understand what went wrong with the codes I tested here and there…
Especially since I think I'm only finding answers that are outdated or don't fit my System language.
So I hope I've shared enough info that you can help me, thanks in advance :)