# How to go to an empty space/desktop with a keyboard shortcut on macOS?

Tags: keyboard, bash, spaces

I'd like to assign a keyboard shortcut to execute the following logic:

Find empty space (with no windows, so just my desktop) and go to it.
If there is no empty space, create one and then go to it.
I use yabai and skhd, which might help. I think there is a way to do it with yabai, but it would require disabling System Integrity Protection, which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 4):

Holy, this was quite a ride to achieve seemingly such a simple result.

---

## TLDR

Requirements:

- `yabai` - for getting info about spaces
- `skhd` or something else for connecting keyboard shortcuts with shell scripts
- `jq` - for parsing json output in the shell
- (optionally) `SpaceLauncher` - if you use it anyway and would like the shortcut to be e.g. <kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> ("D" like Desktop)

If you don't use `yabai` then installing all of the above may be too much. This solution is perhaps only acceptable if you already use `yabai` or intend to use it.

Good news - my solution does not require disabling SIP (System Integrity Protection).

### 1. Ok, let's go. Create the files below in some folder (I put them in `~/.local/scripts/`).

get_empty_space.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash

my_array=($(yabai -m query --spaces --display 1 | jq '.[].windows | any'))
any_space_empty=false
for ((i = 0; i < ${#my_array[@]}; i++)); do
    if ! ${my_array[i]}; then
        echo $((i + 1))
        any_space_empty=true
        break
    fi
done

if ! $any_space_empty; then
    echo false
fi
```

create_space.sh

```bash
open -a 'Mission Control'
sleep 0.1
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to click (every button whose value of attribute "AXDescription" is "add desktop") of group 2 of group 1 of group 1 of process "Dock"'
sleep 0.1
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code 53'
```

switch_space.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash

declare -a desktophash
desktophash[1]=18
desktophash[2]=19
desktophash[3]=20
desktophash[4]=21
desktophash[5]=23
desktophash[6]=22
desktophash[7]=26
desktophash[8]=28
desktophash[9]=25
desktophash[10]=29
desktopkey=${desktophash[$1]}
osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to key code $desktopkey using option down"
```

go_to_desktop.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash

empty_space=$(/Users/yourname/.local/scripts/get_empty_space.sh)
if [ "$empty_space" == "false" ]; then
    /Users/yourname/.local/scripts/create_space.sh
    sleep 0.15
fi
empty_space=$(/Users/yourname/.local/scripts/get_empty_space.sh)
/Users/yourname/.local/scripts/switch_space.sh $empty_space
```

### 2. Next, give the files above executive permissions.

```bash
chmod +x ~/.local/scripts/get_empty_space.sh
chmod +x ~/.local/scripts/create_space.sh
chmod +x ~/.local/scripts/switch_space.sh
chmod +x ~/.local/scripts/go_to_desktop.sh
```

### 3. Assign macOS system shortcuts for spaces.

- Create spaces/desktops so that at least 10 exist before going to the next step.
- Go to **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Mission Control**.
- Assign shortcuts for all 10 **Switch to Desktop N** entries.
- The shortcuts that do not require changing my code above are <kbd>Opt</kbd>+*N*, so <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> goes to space 1 and so on. You can choose different shortcuts but then you will have to modify `switch_space.sh` correspondingly, most likely just the last line of it.

### 4. Assign a shortcut in `skhd` to run `go_to_desktop.sh` script.

In `.skhdrc`  file add a line like this:

```
f4 : /Users/yourname/.local/scripts/go_to_desktop.sh
```

### 4a. (optional step) In SpaceLauncher bind <kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to press <kbd>F4</kbd>.

- Key: <kbd>D</kbd>
- Action: **Simulate Keystroke**
- Key: <kbd>F4</kbd>

### 5. Press the shortcut - you might need to add some permissions to `skhd` before it starts to work.

---

## Explanation and debugging

### 1. If you have a different OS language than US English, you might need to modify `create_space.sh` script.

Based on the [StackOverflow thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/407422/create-a-new-space-using-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-macos-big-sur) where I got my script from, the script below has good chances of working, but is not tested:

```bash
open -b 'com.apple.exposelauncher'
sleep 0.5
osascript -e 'tell application id "com.apple.systemevents" tell (every application process whose bundle identifier = "com.apple.dock") to click (button 1 of group 2 of group 1 of group 1)'
sleep 0.5
osascript -e 'key code 53 -- esc key'
```

The AppleScript from the thread:

```vb
do shell script "open -b 'com.apple.exposelauncher'"
delay 0.5
tell application id "com.apple.systemevents"
    tell (every application process ¬
        whose bundle identifier = "com.apple.dock") to ¬
        click (button 1 of group 2 of group 1 of group 1)
    delay 0.5
    key code 53 -- esc key
end tell
```

### 2. You might need to increase the sleep times in `create_space.sh` and `go_to_desktop.sh` for it to work properly on your mac.

By trial and error and starting from 0.5 seconds, I got down to the times in my scripts. I use an M1 MacBook Pro.

### 3. A short explanation of the scripts.

You can test all the scripts separately to see if they work and what they do.

- **`create_space.sh`** - self explanatory. The space created will be at the end.
- **`switch_space.sh`** - mimicks clicking <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> on the keyboard. It is used like `./switch_space.sh 5` to go to space no. 5.
- **`get_empty_space.sh`** - outputs the integer number of an empty space. If there is no empty space it outputs `false`. The output of this will be an input to `switch_space.sh`.
- **`go_to_desktop.sh`** - the code I think is reasonably readable to explain itself.

Most of the magic happens in the 1st line of `get_empty_space.sh`. The function `yabai -m query --spaces --display` returns something like:

```json
[{
    "index":1,
    "windows":[1350901],
    ...
},
...
]
```

The windows key of every space can tell us whether there are some windows there or not. We pass it to `jq` with this line `yabai -m query --spaces --display | jq '.[].windows'` and get just the windows lists.

```
[
  1350901
]
[
  1357661
]
...
```

Enhance it further with  `| any` and this line `yabai -m query --spaces --display | jq '.[].windows | any'` gives us a list of booleans, where `true` means there are some windows in the given space.

```
true
true
...
```

The rest is quite standard `bash`.

---

## Final thoughts

Isn't it too much for such a "simple" task? It may be. It could probably be achieved with just one bash script instead of 4, but:

- a) I spent a lot of time learning `bash` to make it work and this way was easier for me
- b) those scripts do just one small task each and I expect to find a use for them in other automations as well

Comment: This answer is simply AMAZING! Thank you so much for sharing!

Comment: Thanks, I'm happy that it happened to be useful to somebody :)